# Export single SMS from iPhone and import on another iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, data-transfer, sms

Is there a possibility to sync the messages between two iPhones? Currently, I'm switching from one phone to another, but one device has got a new SMS.

How can I export the single SMS and import it on the other phone? Is the only option through making a complete new backup with iTunes (time consuming and I don't need all data)?

I also tried to enable [iCloud backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86736/how-can-i-transfer-messages-from-iphone-4-to-iphone-5), but it fails every time ...

Comment: To me "single SMS" means one single to message to or from one person.   Also does "new SMS" mean new phone number?

Comment: Yes, one single message. I had my phone with the old number. I made a backup with iTunes and restored it on the new phone (no SIM yet). Now I got a SMS which I also want to have on my new device. (This device now has a new SIM with a new phone number).

Answer (score 1):

If both of your iPhones are jailbroken, you can

1. Login into your old iPhone via SSH
2. Download `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db` file from your iPhone
3. Open the file with `sqlite3` command in your computer or any SQLite client.
4. Get the last message based on timestamps with `SELECT` SQL command.
5. Then login into your new iPhone and open `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db` file with sqlite3 command, and do the reverse action.
6. That means: insert the new message with `INSERT` command

This might work.

Comment: thats good idea @Hamid i will try to check what i have in that db :) thanks.